# Problemas con PDO y PHP

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

Necesito conectarme a una db oracle, para ello estoy usando el siguiente código!

```
<?php  class ConnectionDBTOAD{
private static $conn=null;
private static $server = "mi host";
private static $db_username = "mi usuario";
private static $db_password = "contraseña";
private static $service_name = "serviciox";
private static $sid   = "serviciox";
private static $port  = 1521;
private static $dbtns = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = $server)(PORT = $port)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = $service_name) (SID = $sid)))";
public static function OpenBDTOAD(){
    if (self::$conn==null) {
        try{
            self::$conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=" . self::$dbtns . ";charset=utf8", self::$db_username, self::$db_password, array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return self::$conn;
    }
}
public static function CloseBDTOAD(){
    self::$conn=null;
}}?>
```

sin embargo , en el navegador me sale el mensaje

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in C:\xampp\htdocs\ciclo\model\connectiondt.php on line 9

es decir, el error esta justo en esta linea

```
private static $dbtns = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = $server)(PORT = $port)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = $service_name) (SID = $sid)))";
```

de igual manera ya he modificado el archivo php.ini habilitando

> extension=php_pdo_oci.dll

También he intentado colocar la conexión fuera de una clase y me sale el mismo error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### El problema

No se puede crear una [*propiedad estatica*](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php) (`eg: $dbtns`) en *clases* que dependan de otras, ya que esto implica una `operación` para calcular el valor de la misma. Así mismo, vale mencionar que las variables `$server, $port, etc.` que se encuentran dentro del `string` **no existen**.

[Cita del manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties)

> Las propiedades estáticas sólo pueden ser inicializadas utilizando un string literal o una constante; las expresiones no están permitidas. Por tanto, se puede inicializar una propiedad estática con enteros o arrays (por ejemplo), pero no se puede hacer con otra variable, con el valor de devolución de una función, o con un objeto.

### Solución:

Asignar el valor calculado a la variable `$dbtns` al ejecutar el método `OpenBDTOAD`.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
class ConnectionDBTOAD
{
    private static $conn = null;
    private static $server = "mi host";
    private static $db_username = "mi usuario";
    private static $db_password = "contraseña";
    private static $service_name = "serviciox";
    private static $sid = "serviciox";
    private static $port = 1521;
    private static $dbtns;
    public static function OpenBDTOAD()
    {
        if (self::$conn == null) {

            // AQUI - Asignamos el valor
            self::$dbtns = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = " . self::$server . ")(PORT = " . self::$port . ")) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = " . self::$service_name . ") (SID = " . self::$sid . ")))";
            try {
                self::$conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=" . self::$dbtns . ";charset=utf8", self::$db_username, self::$db_password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            return self::$conn;
        }
    }
    public static function CloseBDTOAD()
    {
        self::$conn = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola marcos!
muchas gracias por responder, sin embargo ya me sale otro error!
could not find driver
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ciclo\model\model.gestiones.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ciclo\view\index.php(12): Gestiones::consulta() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ciclo\model\model.gestiones.php on line 19

Me tiene loco esta conexion ! ya edite el php.ini y sigue saliendo el error ! sabes depronto que pueda ser ?

pdt: si quito la linea 19 ($pdo->setAttribute) el error migra a la siguiente ($pdo->exec)

Comment: @accountflank, ese es otro error que nada tiene que ver con esto. Deberías crear una nueva pregunta y agregar el código del archivo `model.gestiones.php`

Comment: jejeje ok ! dejame la creo y la pongo en un comentario !

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65991/problemas-con-conexion-a-oracle-con-pdo-y-php

marcos ! he ahi la pregunta ! mil gracias por responder ! (Y)