# Problemas con conexion a ORACLE con PDO y PHP

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

hace un momento publique la siguiente pregunta !
[Problemas con PDO y PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65894/problemas-con-pdo-y-php/65924#65924)

una vez corregido el codigo en el archivo de conexion me aparece el siguiente error!

> could not find driver
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ciclo\model\model.gestiones.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ciclo\view\index.php(12): Gestiones::consulta() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ciclo\model\model.gestiones.php on line 19

el codigo que tengo en el archivo model.gestiones.php es el siguiente

```
<?php  
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
class Gestiones
{
    function consulta(){
        $pdo= ConnectionDBTOAD::OpenBDTOAD();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
        $sql=" aqui va la consulta SQL";
        $query= $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        $result=$query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
        ConnectionDBTOAD::CloseBDTOAD();
        return $result;
    }
}?>
```

no se porque me aparece el error ya que el codigo no lo he modificado ( este archivo es un copy/paste de un proyecto que entregue ayer, con la diferencia que era conexion a mysql. )

como dije en la pregunta anterior ! ya he modificado el archivo php.ini quitandole el  punto y coma ( ; ) en la linea en donde esta extension=php_pdo_oci.dll .

De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas ! estare atento !

PDT: este es el codigo de la clase de conexion

```
<?php   class ConnectionDBTOAD{
private static $conn=null;
private static $server = "host";
private static $db_username = "user";
private static $db_password = "contraseña";
private static $service_name = "servicioX";
private static $sid   = "servicioX";
private static $port  = 1521;
private static $dbtns;

public static function OpenBDTOAD(){
    if (self::$conn==null) {
        self::$dbtns = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = " . self::$server . ")(PORT = " . self::$port . ")) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = " . self::$service_name . ") (SID = " . self::$sid . ")))";
        try{
            self::$conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=" . self::$dbtns . ";charset=utf8", self::$db_username, self::$db_password, array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return self::$conn;
    }
}
public static function CloseBDTOAD(){
    self::$conn=null;
}}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que la llamada a `ConnectionDBTOAD::OpenBDTOAD()` devuelve `null`, por lo que `$pdo` vale `null` y no tiene un método que se llame `setAttribute()`.

Deberías reforzar el código y hacer una comprobación del tipo:

```
<?php  
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
class Gestiones
{
    function consulta(){
        $pdo= ConnectionDBTOAD::OpenBDTOAD();
        if (empty($pdo) === true) {
          die('Se produjo un error');
        }
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
        $sql=" aqui va la consulta SQL";
        $query= $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        $result=$query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
        ConnectionDBTOAD::CloseBDTOAD();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Además, te recomiendo reforzar las comprobaciones que haces durante la ejecución de `ConnectionDBTOAD::OpenBDTOAD()` para encontrar la causa raíz del problema:

```
<?php
public static function OpenBDTOAD(){
    if (self::$conn==null) {
        self::$dbtns = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = " . self::$server . ")(PORT = " . self::$port . ")) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = " . self::$service_name . ") (SID = " . self::$sid . ")))";
        try{
            self::$conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=" . self::$dbtns . ";charset=utf8", self::$db_username, self::$db_password, array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            die('Se produjo un error grave y no se puede continuar: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
        return self::$conn;
    }
}
```

Por cierto, ese `could not find driver` suena a que no tienes bien instalado el driver `pdo_oci`. ¿Has probado a mirar la salida de un [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo)? Deberías tener un apartado `PDO` que debe mostrar algo como `PDO drivers: dblib, oci, mysql` y un apartado propio llamado `pdo_oci` que debe tener algo como `PDO Driver for OCI 8 and later - enabled`.

Si no está funcionando la extensión OCI para PDO deberías probar a instalar el [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) (por ejemplo la versión 12.2, la última a día de hoy).

Luego busca la ruta donde se ha instalado (posiblemente se llame "instantclient_12_2") y agrégala a la variable de entorno `PATH`. Reinicia el apache y vuelve a mirar los logs de error en busca de nuevos mensajes de error o advertencia.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58856/discussion-on-answer-by-oscargarcia-problemas-con-conexion-a-oracle-con-pdo-y-ph).

Comment: Si la pregunta te parece interesante, puedes votarle a favor y así "de paso" le ayudas al OP a llegar a 20 de rep para que pueda participar en las salas de chat.